# How do I run Java programs in Ubuntu?

Tags: java

I tried to run a Java program (.jar) in Ubuntu using the default Java (JDK if I'm not mistaken) but I couldn't so I tried to install it following [these instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JRE-on-Ubuntu-Linux) but I still can't.

What should I do?

How do I revert what I just did following that link?

Comment: @SenorTequoia this needs a little more detail. When you say "but I still can't" above, that leaves me no information to help discern why the installation failed, or if it failed for that matter. Please edit your entry to tell me what happens when you type "java --version" at a command prompt. Include your command, and the response seen in the terminal. Also, you state that you "tried to install it following these instructions", please edit your answer and tell us what happened when you tried to install. Did you complete the instructions in the link that you provided ? Did you see errors ?

Comment: paste the output of `javac -version` or `java -version`. if it outputs with version on it, then you have installed java correctly. and then run (if it exists) `java -jar youJarFile.jar`